# Most efficient payment UX model

Tags: mobile-application, conversion, payment

I am trying to understand which payment UX model is the most efficient.

It is about an mobile app providing matrimonial services. I can think of two options:

1. The user enters all user details and then on submit we show him the payment options.
2. Make the user pay first and then move to entering user details.

Which method has the maximum chance for the user to pay or abandon? Are there any stats or analytics explaining this?

Comment: Hi Sajanyamaha, what's your primary goal? Maximizing conversion rate or providing the best User Experience? This could be two different goals...

Comment: hope I dont look greedy green BUT , a solution with best user experience PLUS better conversion would be great . or even conversions can wait , what do you propose ?

Comment: Hi @sajanyamaha, the question that comes to mind is how would the user pay first without knowing who they are in the first place? They need to input their details (such as credit card, address, name, etc..) to be billed. I don't quite get how in this scenario in the second example the user can pay first without giving details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask for payment upfront. I can tell you from experience that this is a UX disaster. One example that comes to mind was the Ouya game console that once you powered it up it asked for payment details, first thing.

Offer value first, earn your user's trust and then ask for payment. Also, consider offering multiple ways of payment and built-in methods (both Google Play and the App Store make this very easy to implement)

Comment: already I have proceeded the same way you have advised , marking it the answer .